# document.getElementById(somevar) not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, getelementbyid

i have the code below but getElementById(setID) not working for me,
i know it catches the id because alert(setID) working.

any idea?

```
function getdata(file, aID){
req = xmlHttpRequestHandler.createXmlHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = Response;
req.open("GET", file, true);
req.send(null);
setID = aID;
}

function Response() { 
    var ready, status;
    try {
        ready = req.readyState;
        status = req.status;
    }
    catch(e) {}
    if (ready == 4 && status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }

   document.getElementById(setID).className = "someclass";
}


<div class="msg" id="someid">
<a href="javascript:getdata('data.php', 'someid')">somelink</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When is the function getdata(...) called? Is it possible that the document hasn't been fully loaded by the time execution reaches getElementById(setID)? Also, shouldn't the className assignment be inside the if(ready... block? In the current implementation, it will get called several times while XHR is handling the request.

Comment: here:
<div class="msg" id="someid">
<a href="javascript:getdata('data.php', 'someid')">somelink</a>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use setID as a global variable or pass it to the callback function.

```
function getdata(file, aID)
{
    req = xmlHttpRequestHandler.createXmlHttpRequest();
    setID = aID;
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {Response(setID);};
    req.open("GET", file, true);
    req.send(null);
}

function Response(setID)
```

Comment: tried that but still not working ( document.getElementById(setID) is null)

Comment: Are you sure your rendered document has an element whose id is the alue of setID? If the element is inside a naming container then you have to use ClientID to get the id of that particular element.

Comment: the setID is globally defined. and the script is OK, i found no problem in this script.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
document.getElementById("data")
```

doesn't work, this has one of the following reasons in 99% of all cases:

- The element does not exist or exist anymore
- There are more than one element with the id `data`

This happens often when the AJAX call introduces HTML code that also contains an element with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making your `setID` variable global? If not then try this:

```
var setID = null; // we set this here because it is referenced in functions

function getdata(file, aID){
req = xmlHttpRequestHandler.createXmlHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = Response;
req.open("GET", file, true);
req.send(null);
setID = aID;
}

function Response() { 
    var ready, status;
    try {
        ready = req.readyState;
        status = req.status;
    }
    catch(e) {}
    if (ready == 4 && status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }

   document.getElementById(setID).className = "someclass";
}
```